# PHP email with event invitation

Tags: php, events, phpmailer

I have this event website that uses PHPMailer with zoho mail SMTP to send a confirm email after the register process. The code work well, it sends the email an all.

When you recieve and email about your travel ticket on gmail, Gmail automatically creates an event on my calendar. How can I make the same thing about my event? Not only working for gmail but for every person that uses hotmail or any other email service.

Comment: I think Google and other services do this by attaching an `.ics` file to the email.  I'm not entirely familiar with the ICS standard, but essentially it's just a text file with information in a specific format and an `.ics` file extension.  You could create that in-memory and attach it to the email.

Comment: generate ics file. maybe this link would help you. https://icalendar.org/php-library.html

Comment: Thank you, you definitely point me to the right direction. I found a couple of ics generators on the web, it was as easy as attach the file to the email.